# Create a custom Date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to build a dataframe of crypto prices using various different exchange API's, and the problem I'm having is each exchange has slight gaps in their data, but don't leave the gaps blank to let me fill fwd for example.

My solution is to take the earliest date from the data I have, and create a separate column that contains every hour of every day up until now and try and force the gaps in the data to open up by merging `on='Date'` onto this new Date column, so I can then fill fwd for the missing prices.

So I'm looking to create a column like this for example that continues up until right now. And I have no idea where to start! Any help would be really appreciated cheers.

```
                  Date
0  2019-04-26 16:00:00
1  2019-04-26 17:00:00
2  2019-04-26 18:00:00
3  2019-04-26 19:00:00
4  2019-04-26 20:00:00
5  2019-04-26 21:00:00
6  2019-04-26 22:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2019-04-26 16:00:00', 
                                            '2019-04-26 22:00:00', 
                                            freq='H')
                      })
```

Output:

```
                 Date
0 2019-04-26 16:00:00
1 2019-04-26 17:00:00
2 2019-04-26 18:00:00
3 2019-04-26 19:00:00
4 2019-04-26 20:00:00
5 2019-04-26 21:00:00
6 2019-04-26 22:00:00
```

Comment: Hi mate yes this is what I am after thanks, just out of interest is there a way to give the program 3 different dates, in that format, and it returns the oldest date? Many thanks

Comment: You mean like `min( (date1, date2, date3))`?

Comment: Perrrrfect, sorry I wasn't sure if I needed to convert to some number or something first. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Base on your description you can using `resample`+ `ffill`

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('H').mean().ffill()
```

Comment: Hi mate, I think I see where you are going with this, and this might indeed be quicker for me. Should this function you wrote make the index every hour for every date and then fwd fill for me? I tried it but receive this error message `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`. Thanks again

Comment: @topbantz then you just do with group by and resemble